# Understanding Lexicon FST in yesno example of Kaldi

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, state-machine, kaldi, finite-state-automaton

[image]

I am running yesno example in Kaldi. I could get 0 WER at the output, which means things are going right. However, when I tried to view the L.FST, I see some ambiguity.

Consider the above L.FST , how to choose the next state from the current state 1, for the input trigger symbol of SIL? Not just SIL, but for any input symbol, I could not find this L.FST to be useful.

I see that state 0 is important for composition. But what does state 1 and 2 represent?